# SQL: Performing substraction only when record exists

Tags: sql

I have three tables with: parts data, orders data and shipped data.
Trying to write stored procedure which returns part number, name etc and quantity of parts which are still to be shipped.

When some parts from certain order have already been shipped - we have to substract that quantity from total number of parts ordered with that order.
When no parts from certain order have been shipped yet - we have to show number of ordered parts.

I have so far tried:

```
PROCEDURE dbo.GetParts
AS
SELECT od.OrderDetailID, od.PartNr, od.OrderNr, d.PartName, RemainsToBeShipped =
CASE 
WHEN EXISTS(SELECT sh.Quantity FROM Shipped AS sh WHERE sh.OrderDetailID = od.OrderDetailID)
THEN od.Quantity - sh.Quantity
ELSE od.Quantity
END
FROM OrderDetails AS od, Parts AS d, Shipped as s
WHERE od.NrDet = d.NrDet AND od.OrderDetailID = s.OrderDetailID
```

This does not work - part after "ELSE" never fires.

Comment: If you take one example OrderDetailID that you know has at least one record in Shipped and run that (SELECT sh.Quantity...) subquery or add (SELECT SUM(sh.Quantity)...) as a test column in your main SELECT statement, are you getting the values that you'd expect?  If you can get the subquery to behave you might also consider doing something like 
`SELECT od.OrderDetailID,...,od.Quantity - ISNULL(SELECT SUM(sh.Quantity)...),0) AS RemainsToBeShipped`
because that should always give you the correct result without the CASE.

Comment: You are inner joining to the Shipped table, so it would only ever give you items shipped. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    od.OrderDetailID, od.PartNr, od.OrderNr, d.PartName
    , od.Quantity - ISNULL(s.Quantity,0) [RemainsToBeShipped]
FROM OrderDetails AS od
INNER JOIN Parts AS d ON od.NrDet = d.NrDet
LEFT JOIN Shipped as s ON od.OrderDetailID = s.OrderDetailID
```

Comment: @Lukas2 I recommend staying away from the older style of joins where you list all your table and then the join conditions are in the WHERE clause. I think it makes it much harder to read and really wrap your head around for complicated queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your joins prevent you from getting ANY unshipped items.   Try this:

```
SELECT od.OrderDetailID, od.PartNr, od.OrderNr, d.PartName, RemainsToBeShipped =
 od.Quantity - ISNULL(s.Quantity,0)
FROM OrderDetails AS od
INNER JOIN Parts AS d ON od.NrDet = d.NrDet 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Shipped AS s ON od.OrderDetailID = s.OrderDetailID
```